# Re-order data of CSV file in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset that are read from CSV file:

```
1   6.5
2   12
3   9
4   16.2
5   7.5
1   13
2   6
3   2.8
4   26
5   30
```

I would like to move the data of the second group (starting from 13 to 30) to be like:

```
1   6.5   13
2   12    6
3   9     2.8
4   16.2  26
5   7.5   30
```

Note that this data will be written to CSV file.

How can I do that? I didn't know how to do it in R

Answer (score 1):

After readng the dataset (`read.csv` from `base R` or `fread` from `data.table` or `read_csv` from `rowr`), create a column of column names after grouping by 'col1' and then `spread` the 'col2' with 'colN'

```
library(tidvyerse)
df1 %>%
   group_by(col1) %>%
   mutate(colN = str_c("newcol_", row_number())) %>% 
   spread(colN, col2)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   col1 [5]
#   col1 newcol_1 newcol_2
#  <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1      6.5     13  
#2     2     12        6  
#3     3      9        2.8
#4     4     16.2     26  
#5     5      7.5     30
```

#### data

```
df1 <-structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L
  ), col2 = c(6.5, 12, 9, 16.2, 7.5, 13, 6, 2.8, 26, 30)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Some "hack". You can re`name` and also remove `row.names`.

```
df2<-df[duplicated(df$V1),]
df1<-df[!duplicated(df$V1),]
res<-cbind(df2,df1)
res[,c(2,ncol(res))]
```

Result:

```
     V2 V2.1
6  13.0  6.5
7   6.0 12.0
8   2.8  9.0
9  26.0 16.2
10 30.0  7.5
```

Data:

```
df<-read.table(text="1   6.5
2   12
               3   9
               4   16.2
               5   7.5
               1   13
               2   6
               3   2.8
               4   26
               5   30",header=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in one line by using `data.table` and `splitstackshape` package-

```
> library(splitstackshape)
> library(data.table)
> cSplit(setDT(dt)[, list(text=paste(V2, collapse=',')), by = V1],"text")

   V1 text_1 text_2
1:  1    6.5   13.0
2:  2   12.0    6.0
3:  3    9.0    2.8
4:  4   16.2   26.0
5:  5    7.5   30.0
```

**OR**

One other complex solution-

```
> dcast(dt, V1~V2 ,value.var="V2")
> data.table::as.data.table(t(apply( df, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))))[,.(V1,`1_6.5`,`1_13`)]

       V1 1_6.5 1_13
    1:  1   6.5   13
    2:  2   6.0   12
    3:  3   2.8    9
    4:  4  16.2   26
    5:  5   7.5   30
```